# Views Taxonomy Term Argument With Multiple Terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Hello I am having a torrid time creating a views block. Let me try to explain without rambling on about nothing as I usually do.

I have a content type (links) which uses the same vocab as my other content type (posts) When viewing a Post I was hoping to display any links that have the same terms.

Ive set it up with an Argument Taxonomy: Term ID. It all works as hoped when I have just ONE term on a post but when I have more than one term things start to get a bit strange.

Actually I should mention that I am using Load default argument from node page and just doing it on term id. I am not using Allow multiple terms per argument box. this returns no results (for nodes with multiple terms)

If I change the Argument type: to term id's seprated by ....+ etc I do get a return but it only shows links for one of the terms. Funny enough the term results are for the term that I dont want to use. I have changed the term weights and everything to try and change it to show the links for the term I was hoping for but I dont seem to be able to influence what terms results appear in the views box I have made.. Its got me tearing my hair out.

Can anyone understand my gibberish and offer any solutions?

Comment: I'm going to try to reproduce this problem on my dev site. Any way you could take a screenshot of your settings and post a link to make this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have sort of worked out a solution. It displays correctly in the Views preview but not on the node itself. Maybe this will help though.

View settings:

Create a Block. Configure Block to display on content of type Post. Configure settings of View:

### Fields

- Content: Title

### Filter criteria

- Content: Published (Yes)
- Content: Type (= Links)

### Contextual filters

- (field_tags) Content: Title

  - Using relationship: Term

### Relationships

- Content: Taxonomy terms on node (term)
- Taxonomy term: Content using Tags

  - Using relationship: term

In my preview, when I enter the title of a Post as the contextual filter, I get a list of all the links tagged with the same tags as the Post. For some reason, when I view the actual Post it doesn't work but that might just be a caching issue or something on my end?